# How can I see Fast Fourier Transform makes sense by an easy example

Tags: performance, numpy, scipy, transform, fft

Lets assume the the theory of fourier analysis is clear.
I only want to see that the fast fourier transfom give me somehow, what I would expect from the theory.
For the example below, I would expect in a plot (amplitude over frequency) somehow a peak of 0.5 over 2 and a peak of 1 over 5. How I could see this point? Or where I am running in the wrong direction?

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft

N = 100
x = np.linspace(0.0, 1, N)
y = np.sin(5 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(2 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
yf = fft(y)*(x[1]-x[0])
freq = scipy.fftpack.rfftfreq(N, x[1]-x[0])

plt.plot(freq, np.abs(yf))
```

Thanks to the suggestion from Ammon, I corrected the typo and added a scaling of the step size. But still I don't find a peak of 0.5 over 2 and a peak of 1 over 5.

Comment: when I wrote some golang code to implement an inverse Fourier Transform from scratch this took me over the hump  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGsMWi_j4Q # Discrete Fourier Transform - Simple Step by Step   ... that short video outlines a minimal data and algo walk through on paper   and for more detail see   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htCj9exbGo0

Comment: `rfftfreq` corresponds to `rfft`, try `fftfreq` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to see peaks, you need to plot fft, not input data in meaning yf, not y:

```
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(yf))
```

Have you tried this tutorial:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from Scott Stentsland here is the solution.
Showing a peak of 2 over 2 and a peak of 5 over 5 as defined
in the function.

```
import numpy as np

dt = 0.001
T = np.arange(0,1,dt)
n = len(T)
y = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t) + 5*np.sin(2*np.pi*5*t)


y_fft = np.fft.fft(y,n)                
amplitude = (2 * np.sqrt(y_fft * np.conj(y_fft)))/n           
freq = (1/(dt*n))* np.arange(n)     

L = np.arange(1,np.floor(n/2),dtype='int') # For Nyquist limit 

fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,1)

plt.sca(axs[0])
plt.plot(t,f,color='c',LineWidth=1.5)
plt.xlim(t[0],t[-1])
plt.legend()

plt.sca(axs[1])
plt.scatter(freq[L],amplitude[L],color='k')
plt.xlim(0,7)
plt.legend()
```